# Mysql parse error

Tags: php, mysql

Can anyone help me fix this MySQL query? I cant figure out what i am doing wrong.

```
for ($i=1;$i<=12;$i++) {

mysql_query(UPDATE bbank SET created=NOW() + INTERVAL $i MINUTES WHERE bankID='$i' );

}
```

**ERROR:**

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in
>   E:\stuff\www\test\roger.php on line 19

I've tried adding brackets, quotes, etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be `MINUTE` and not `MINUTES` also missing quotes for whole query:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE bbank SET created=NOW() + INTERVAL $i MINUTE WHERE bankID='$i'");
```

Comment: Yes, thats the main problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Missing the quotes around the SQL query :

```
mysql_query("UPDATE bbank SET created=NOW() + INTERVAL $i MINUTES WHERE bankID='$i'");
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed the quotes

```
mysql_query("UPDATE bbank SET created=NOW() + INTERVAL $i MINUTES WHERE bankID='$i'");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mysql_query("UPDATE bbank SET created=NOW() + INTERVAL $i MINUTES WHERE bankID='$i'");
```

you didn't create a string so PHP thought it was code